# Why are my ExpandableList listeners never called?

Tags: android

I have a `ExpandableListView` and I dont know why my listeners are never called when I click on a child. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // ...

        this.getExpandableListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Log.v("test", "short");
                // not working when I click on a child
            }
        });

        this.getExpandableListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Log.v("test", "long");
                // not working when I click on a child
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer [Expandable ListView Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/).. All the steps and code given in this tutorial.. You can get clear idea.. All the best..